# How can I bypass the call to destructor at end of member function?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a struct with a non-trivial non-copyable (anyway, copyable but very expensive) member and there's a member function that I want if I call, it would transfer the ownership of the member. See the following demo code:

```
class A{
    // ...
};
struct s{
    A instance;
    A? take(){ // originally named get(), as mentioned in comment, for clarity
        return instance?;
    }
}; // Even after s is destroyed, instance should keep on
```

In other words, I want to prolong the life of `instance`, then use it in other context. I tried several ways, including `return std::move(instance)` or explicit release the object to a temporary variable, but none of them worked. They will always call the destructor of instance.

So how can I achieve that, will returning const reference help?

Comment: Make it `static`? Or declare it on the namespace level.

Comment: The `instance` is unique to every instance of `s`, kinda awkward. So static is not feasible.

Comment: Who is going to *own* this instance if not the instance of `s`? Somebody has to *own* this, or it has to *be scoped*.

Comment: Why is it imperative the destructor is not called?

Comment: @Nawaz, by some variable (external with respect to the struct) in other function.

Comment: If A is to outlive S it cannot be an instance member of S by value. You need to make it a pointer or reference. What you're presently asking for embodies a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @YiFei: If some other class is going to *own* this, then I think that should define the instances, and the instances of `s` should have the references to them.

Comment: @Nawaz, Yeah, exactly, seems I've been trapped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- An object's lifetime *cannot* be extended beyond its lexical scope, unless it has static or thread storage duration.
- You *cannot* suppress the implicit destructor call for an object that goes out of scope, other than by calling `std::exit` or otherwise crashing the program.

This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Most likely, the actual solution is to have `take()` return `A` (by value) and use `std::move` to move the resources from `s::instance` to the return value, so that the destructor of `s::instance` is a no-op.

```
A take() {
    return std::move(instance);
}
```

But we can't say for sure if you won't tell us the actual problem.

Comment: So in this way, the external function and the struct will share the ownership, and would be very dangerous if the struct dies out, right?

Comment: @YiFei if you write the move constructor correctly, all ownership of resources will be transferred from `instance` to the returned object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the move constructor of instance correctly, so that it takes the resources and leaves the source as an empty shell. Then std::move() will turn the member into the shell, and give you a full object you can do what you want with. The destructor will still be called, but will be essentially a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this, i.e. avoid the destructor call entirely, is with a smart pointer:

```
struct s
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> instance;
    std::unique_ptr<A> get() { return std::move(instance); }
};
```

If you want a default-constructed `s` to contain an `A` then give `s` a constructor such as :

```
s(): instance( new A ) {}
```

You could use perfect forwarding to pass constructor arguments onto A's constructor if desired.

---

Another possible solution (which I have used in a pre-C++11 codebase) is to give `A` a mutable boolean flag named `active`; and then have the copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator "move" this flag during the operation. Then the destructor only destroys resources for instances where the flag is set.  But in C++11 this is no longer necessary due to the availability of move semantics.